# How restore initial values of buttons in ajax request success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my request AJAX, in beforesend i disable all buttons, because in my opinion is better choice of security.
In the success i enable all button  again. But i have many other buttons in my page, and i need restart default disabled status after success request.

Have one method from obtain  value set in beforesend and set this correct disabled status after in the success?

Because in my code i enable all buttons in success, but i need restore disabled status exactly as beforerequest.

below my simple code.

```
            $.ajax({
            url     :"/action/controller.php",                      
            type    :"POST",
            data    : data.serialize()
                    + '&'
                    + encodeURI('action')
                    + '='
                    + encodeURI(action)
                    + '&'
                    + encodeURI('tableid')
                    + '='
                    + encodeURI(tableid)
                    + '&'
                    + encodeURI('id')
                    + '='
                    + encodeURI(id),
            beforeSend: function(){
                //imgload.fadeIn('slow');
                $('button').attr('disabled', true);
                //console.log ($('button[name="action"]'));
                },
            success: function(retorno){
                //console.log( retorno );
                //msg(retorno, 'info');
                datagrid();
                $('form').unbind('submit').bind('submit');
                $('button').attr('disabled', false);
            }
```

html:

```
    <button id="formbutton" type="button"  data-action="back" data-tableid="<?php echo $tableid; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="Voltar" value="back">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</button>
<button id="formbutton" type="button" data-action="new" data-tableid="<?php echo $tableid; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="Novo" value="new">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Novo
</button>
<button id="formbutton" type="submit" data-action="save" data-tableid="<?php echo $tableid; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="Salvar" value="save">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Salvar
</button>
<button id="formbutton" type="submit" data-action="delete" data-tableid="<?php echo $tableid; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="Delete" value="delete">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Excluir
</button>
<button id="formbutton" type="submit" data-action="edit" data-tableid="<?php echo $tableid; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="Editar" value="edit">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Editar
</button>
<button id="formbutton" type="submit" data-action="duplicate" data-tableid="<?php echo $tableid; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="Duplicar" value="duplicate">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Duplicar
</button>
<button id="formbutton" type="submit" data-action="next" data-tableid="<?php echo $tableid; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="Proximo" value="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Not certain what your Question is ? Which portion of `js` is not returning expected results ?

Comment: I can get DISABLED status beforesend, and set this correctly after in sucess...
Because i have buttons with disabled = true on beforesend.

i have one menu with buttons and they have diferents status in DISABLED. I Can get restore default after request

Comment: Yes, `js` at Question appears to set `button` elements to `disabled` : `true` at `beforeSend` and `disabled`: `false` at `success` . Is `js` at Question not returning expected results ? Missing closing `)` at `$.ajax()` ?

Comment: in my script all buttons set enable after success, but i need restore exactly 
just like beforesend. undestand?

Comment: Yes, `js` at `beforeSend` sets all `button` elements to `disabled` because it uses selector `button`. Similarly at `success`. Can you include `html` at Question ? Which specific `button` element do you want to set `disabled` to `true` , then `false` at `success` ?

Comment: There are duplicate `id` at `html`. `id` of element should be unique in document

Comment: imagine that I am entering a new record, then my buttons delete , duplicate , next ... they are disabled by default .
When I click save send the request to the ajax , but they all come back turned and I would like to capture the status at the beginning and assign the same status after the return .

Comment: would like to return the status of the button, a command to return the same status it had before sending the request

Comment: Try substituting `class="formbutton"` for `id="formbutton"` for valid `html` document without duplicate `id`s. Only `button` having attribute `data-action="save"` should be disabled, enabled ?

Comment: but i need make tests with IF for this, right? Don't have one command to return  exactly just like beforesend? this is my question =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class on the buttons you just disable, and disable only enabled buttons, then you just have to enable the buttons with your class :

```
beforeSend: function(){
  //imgload.fadeIn('slow');
  $('button:enabled').addClass('toEnable').attr('disabled', true);
  //console.log ($('button[name="action"]'));
},
success: function(retorno){
  //console.log( retorno );
  //msg(retorno, 'info');
  datagrid();
  $('form').unbind('submit').bind('submit');
  $('button.toEnable').removeClass('toEnable').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: To improve it, you can try to add a data and not a class, it will be less a "tweak" and it will work the same.

Comment: I will try to create a function to capture what operation will be performed , and so enable and disable the buttons identifying them by ID , you will really get much better .
I did not have no idea how to start , I now have several . Thank you.